# Make vue ignore objects during reactivity walk?

Tags: performance, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

Is there a way to make vue ignore/exclude an object from it's "reactivity walk"?

We have a vue app controlling an editor for google maps Polylines and I have noticed that when it is first mounted the page takes a huge performance hit (i.e freezing for 6 seconds every mount). I can see in the firefox performance tab that most of this time is spent by `we.prototype.walk` in `vue.min.js` and I assume this is vue making the google maps object reactive and halting the page due to its size.

I therefore want to mark the map object as "ignored" by vue as the component/app does not need access to it, is there a way to do this?

Our structure is something akin to this:

Component.vue

```js
<template>...</template>
<script>
    ...vue_stuff,
    props: ["tool"] // <--- This ìs the "editor" object
```

Editor.js

```js
class Editor{
    constructor(map, line){
        this.map = map; // <--- This is the google maps object 
        this.line = line; // <--- This is the Polyline object, the editor must have access to this
                          // The line also contains a reference to the map, 
                          // so it is no use to remove it from the object
        this.undoStack = []; // <--- The vue component must have access to this + functions
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by adding a dummy observer to the map object, inspired by / stolen from https://github.com/rpkilby/vue-nonreactive. This makes vue "believe" it already have scanned the object and therefore ignores it.

After the map object is initialized I create the dummy observer with

```js
map.__ob__ = new (new Vue()).$data.__ob__.constructor({})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should remove the reactivity from the map property:

```
this["map"] = map;
```

Comment: This did not seem to have any meaningful impact, sadly. The problem is not that the map object IS reactive, it is the initial process of vue MAKING it reactive that seems to be the big culprit here.